# Incremental next month dates in SQL

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012

I have similar requirement, i have file feeding to `SQL Server 2012` for a month but i wanted to convert the same file as a next month file.

For Example I have below

```
02/22/2018 02/23/2018 02/24/2018
```

and I want `03/22/2018 03/23/2018 02/24/2018`

I am able to get upto this point but facing issue when i have below situation.

```
02/28/2018 02/24/2018
```

and I want `03/31/2018 03/31/2018`

I have a normal calendar set up which I can use Can somebody please help.

Comment: I don't fully understand, do you have a table with these values? Is it a file? Are those 3 values 3 different columns or a long string? You say you arrived up to a half-solution, can you add your code attempt?

Comment: Hi, sorry if i am not clear, let me elaborate further. 
I have XML file feeding to SQL Server 2012. There a loader job which does this and I can tweak/enhance data in this script.
So I want a query/solution to convert current month dates to next month dates, I am able solve it half. But i am facing problem when I have February file into March file.
E.g. :- 02/28 needs to be converted as 03/28, 03/29, 03/30, 03/31.

Comment: @Aniket on what basis will one date be converted to 4 different dates?

Answer (score 0):

you can use DATEADD() function for this like below :

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, '02/22/2018') AS DateAdd;
```

Comment: Thanks but facing issues when I have 02/28 to convert to 03/28, 03/29, 03/30, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for EOMONTH function

somethink like this might help you solve your issue

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(10) = '02/28/2019'

SELECT CASE WHEN (EOMONTH(@date) = FORMAT(CAST(@date AS DATETIME),'yyyy-MM-dd')) 
                  THEN EOMONTH(DATEADD(month,1,@date))
            ELSE  DATEADD(month,1,@date)
       END
```

**Note:** I have used format function because EOMONTH returns date in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format

**UPDATE**

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE
(
  FromDate DATETIME, 
  ToDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @dates (FromDate)
VALUES('12/31/2017'),('1/31/2018'),('2/28/2018'),('3/31/2018')



select * from @dates

UPDATE @dates 
SET ToDate =CASE WHEN (EOMONTH(FromDate) = FORMAT(CAST(FromDate AS DATETIME),'yyyy-MM-dd')) 
                  THEN EOMONTH(DATEADD(month,1,FromDate))
            ELSE  DATEADD(month,1,FromDate)
       END

       SELECT * FROM @dates
```

Run this and you can see the final output

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for confusion. I need below to be happen.                                                                                           FROM Value                                                                                     12/31/2017, 1/31/2018, 2/28/2018, 3/31/2018                            TO Value
1/31/2018, 2/28/2018, 3/31/2018, 4/30/2018